# Get value using getElementsbyClassName

Tags: html, vba, ms-access

I have been using this function to get value of a stock price from Yahoo! Finance:

```
html.getElementsByClassName("Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").Item(0).innerText
```

The website that I use is (example ticker IQ): https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/?p=IQ

But recently, maybe due to an upgrade, this class throws up an error. Running through the html variable I find that now it's renamed as: `("Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)")`.

I have the full text here, I just want to know how can I get the value of the ticker from this element.

```
    <DIV class="D(ib) Mend(20px)" data-reactid="52">
        <FIN-STREAMER class="Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="53" active="" value="4.71" data-trend="none" data-field="regularMarketPrice" data-symbol="IQ" data-test="qsp-price" data-pricehint="4">
            4.7100
        </FIN-STREAMER>
        <FIN-STREAMER class="Fw(500) Pstart(8px) Fz(24px)" data-reactid="54" active="" value="-0.8800001" data-trend="txt" data-field="regularMarketChange" data-symbol="IQ" data-test="qsp-price-change" data-pricehint="4">
            <SPAN class=C($negativeColor)>-0.8800</SPAN>
        </FIN-STREAMER>
        <!-- react-text: 55 -->
        <!-- /react-text -->
        <FIN-STREAMER class="Fw(500) Pstart(8px) Fz(24px)" data-reactid="56" active="" value="-0.15742399" data-trend="txt" data-field="regularMarketChangePercent" data-symbol="IQ" data-template="({fmt})" data-pricehint="4">
            <SPAN class=C($negativeColor)>(-15.74%)</SPAN>
        </FIN-STREAMER>
        <FIN-STREAMER class=D(n) data-reactid="57" active="true" value="" data-trend="none" data-field="regularMarketTime" data-symbol="IQ" changeev="regularTimeChange">
        </FIN-STREAMER>
        <FIN-STREAMER class=D(n) data-reactid="58" active="true" value="" data-trend="none" data-field="marketState" data-symbol="IQ" changeev="marketState">
        </FIN-STREAMER>
```

The value I want to get out is 4.7100.

What I'm using is:

```
html.getElementsByClassName("Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)").Item(0).innerText
```

But this returns an empty result.

Comment: Consider using `querySelectorAll` instead, and replace the spaces with `.` characters, that way the actual order of the class-names within the class-list won't break your program.

Comment: Better idea: select using the other attributes, e.g. `querySelectorAll( 'IN-STREAMER[data-symbol="IQ"i][data-test-="qsp-price"i]' )` (the `i` part makes it a case-insensitive match).

Comment: Pretty sure the `i` is  not supported in vba.

Comment: Note that that site has specifically been designed to change things up to resist scraping. If you want financial data, get it from an API, it'll be much easier and less prone to breaking

Answer (score 3):

Move away from dynamic classes as these are prone to break and instead look for stable attributes/relationships between elements. I would have the following:

```
html.querySelector("#quote-header-info [data-field=regularMarketPrice]").innerText
```

This uses the id `quote-header-info` to anchor a parent reducing the matches within the following selectors to one. The space before the `[data-field=regularMarketPrice]` is a descendant combinator specifying what follows is a descendant element in the DOM. The `[data-field=regularMarketPrice]` is an attribute = value css selector targeting the desired node by its `data-field` attribute and associated value.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry but I'm a beginner at this, I went ahead and tried your code exactly as such to no effect. I don't know if you wrote it in pseudo or was this the exact which I had to try. If you can provide an example that would be of much help. Thank you once again for your time.

Comment: You need to do something with it e.g. `debug.print` it, or assign it to a cell or `msgbox` it. How did you incorporate the line above into your code? E.g. `Range("B2") =  html.querySelector("#quote-header-info [data-field=regularMarketPrice]").innerText`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's on ACCESS so was basically saving it into a variable:
`stockprice = html.querySelector("#quote-header-info [data-field=regularMarketPrice]").innerText`
I also tried `debug.print` on it as well and it returns empty.

Comment: Have you checked 1) the response status 2) the response text to see if there is any info there? You may be being served an unexpected response. Also, are you requesting with browser automation or xmlhttp? If the latter, then be sure to add a user-agent header to the request.

Comment: Using XMLHTTP: 
`Set request = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`
I did check the response text and there is a lot of text that can be parsed. As a temporary fix I'm using this code: `html.getElementsByClassName("D(ib) Mend(20px)").Item(1).innerText` to get a bunch of stuff out. This gets me the price, increase or decrease, time etc. I then parse it using logic to only get the stock price out. But it is a very band-aid (temporary) method.